# Count appended files / output Stream JAVA

Tags: java, outputstream

I have the following OutputStream which saves SQL receiving BLOB to a network drive. The boolean "true" affects that files which are already there dont get overwritten.

In conclusion, if there are 500 BLOB's in the buffer but 200 of them already saved to the network drive before, only 300 new files will be added.

Question: How could I count the new files?
I want to write a them to a logfile.

Thanks in advance!

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path + "\\" + xy +".jpg", true);
byte[] buff = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
out.write(buff);
out.close();
```

Comment: You can test if the file exists before writing with [File#exists()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists())

Comment: Thank you, works fine. :)